# Second Element Does Not Close On Click Outside

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have Problem With **jQuery**:
In the following code, I want to close **Sidenav** by clicking outside when it opens
The problem is that when **left sidenav** is opened it no longer closes because the **right sidenav** is an element that was created before **left sidenav** and i do not know how to solve this problem

```js
$("[data-open-sidenav]").on("click", function () {
  console.log($(`#${$(this).data("open-sidenav")}`));

  if (
    $(this).data("open-sidenav").length > 0 &&
    $(`#${$(this).data("open-sidenav")}`).length
  ) {
    $(`#${$(this).data("open-sidenav")}`).animate(
      {
        left: "0",
      },
      300
    );
  }
});

$(window).on("click", function () {
  if (parseInt($(".sidenav").css("left")) === 0) {
    $(".sidenav").animate(
      {
        left: "-400px",
      },
      300,
      "linear"
    );
  }
});

$(".sidenav").on("click", function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 400px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: -400px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid @gray;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav li a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <button class="blue" data-open-sidenav="leftsn">Open Left Sidenav</button>
    <button class="blue" data-open-sidenav="rightsn">Open Right Sidenav</button>
    <div id="rightsn" class="sidenav right">
      <li>Right Sidenav</li>
    </div>
    <div id="leftsn" class="sidenav">
      <li>Left Sidenav</li>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two `.sidenav` elements in the DOM. Accessing them by `css()` will return the requested property from the first one *only*.

As such you need to loop through them and test individually before animating, if necesssary:

```js
$("[data-open-sidenav]").on("click", e => {
  let $target = $(`#${$(e.target).data("open-sidenav")}`);
  $target.animate({ left: 0 }, 300);
});

$(document).on("click", () => {
  $('.sidenav').each((i, el) => {
    let $el = $(el);
    if (parseInt($el.css("left")) === 0) {
      $el.animate({ left: "-400px" }, 300, "linear");
    }
  });
});

$(".sidenav").on("click", e => e.stopPropagation());
```

```css
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 400px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: -400px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid @gray;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav li a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="blue" data-open-sidenav="leftsn">Open Left Sidenav</button>
<button class="blue" data-open-sidenav="rightsn">Open Right Sidenav</button>
<div id="rightsn" class="sidenav right">
  <li>Right Sidenav</li>
</div>
<div id="leftsn" class="sidenav">
  <li>Left Sidenav</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this jQuery Plugin to archive this behaviour. Its a plugin which allows you to set `Clickout-Events` to Elements.

https://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/Simple-jQuery-Click-Outside-Plugin-clickout-js.html

Answer (score 1):

The below solution works, all I have done is added a event.stopPropagation to the button clicks on the sidenav buttons, and removed the check in your hide function.

I think the issue was that the function that was checking the value of `left` was only checking the first incidence of the sidenav that it found - i.e. the right sidenav. Thats why it worked for the right but not the left.

Let me know if there was something else.

---

```js
$("[data-open-sidenav]").on("click", function () {
  console.log($(`#${$(this).data("open-sidenav")}`));
  
  // Stop the event propogation so that the sidenav doesnt automatically close
  event.stopPropagation();

  if (
    $(this).data("open-sidenav").length > 0 &&
    $(`#${$(this).data("open-sidenav")}`).length
  ) {
    $(`#${$(this).data("open-sidenav")}`).animate(
      {
        left: "0",
      },
      300
    );
  }
});

$(".sidenav").on("click", function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});

$(window).on("click", function () {

// If there is any click (that is not stopped by the event.stopPropagations)
// Hide any sidenav
    $(".sidenav").animate(
      {
        left: "-400px",
      },
      300,
      "linear"
    );
});
```

```css
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 400px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: -400px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid @gray;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav li a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <button class="blue" data-open-sidenav="leftsn">Open Left Sidenav</button>
    <button class="blue" data-open-sidenav="rightsn">Open Right Sidenav</button>
    <div id="rightsn" class="sidenav right">
      <li>Right Sidenav</li>
    </div>
    <div id="leftsn" class="sidenav">
      <li>Left Sidenav</li>
    </div>
```